# Updating React Props

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why I can use  `push` to mutate the props, but when I try `this.props.arr1 = 2;` I get the following error:

> TypeError: "arr" is read-only

Here is my code:

```
var Demo=React.createClass({
    test1:function(){
        this.props.arr1=2;
        console.log(this.props.arr1);//TypeError: "arr" is read-only
    },
    test2:function(){
        this.props.arr2.push(2);
        console.log(this.props.arr2);//Array [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    getDefaultProps:function(){
        return {arr1:1,arr2:[1]};
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.test1}>demo1</div>
                <div onClick={this.test2}>demo2</div>
            </div>
        )
    },
});

ReactDOM.render(<Demo /> , document.body);
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking why you shouldn't mutate props?

Comment: yes ,i don`t know why i can ues ' push ' to mutate the props,but when i try' this.props.arr1=2;',something is wrong and waring:read-only,

Comment: In React, the idea is to modify state, `this.state`, but only by calling `this.setState({ key: value })` which will cause React to.. well.. React (call `render()` for you). Modifying props does not do this for you so there's no sense in doing it.

Comment: Why would you want to modify the props the component was given? It doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Props should be reserved for data that isn't going to change, think settings/config data, etc. State on the other hand should contain data that a component's event handlers may change to trigger a UI update.

As you are changing the value of the data you should use state instead of props. For your example you would do the following:

```
var Demo = React.createClass({

    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
          foo : 1,
          bar : [1]
        };
    },

    setFoo:function(){
        this.state.foo = 2;
        this.setState({ foo : this.state.foo });
        console.log(this.state.foo);
    },

    setBar:function(){
      this.state.bar.push(2);
      this.setState({ bar : this.state.bar });
      console.log(this.state.bar);
    },

    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.setFoo}>demo1</div>
                <div onClick={this.setBar}>demo2</div>
            </div>
        )
    },
});

ReactDOM.render(<Demo /> , document.body);
```